# Generate a single perl file from multiple files (.pm + .pl)

Tags: perl

A good example of what I would like to do is [Ack](http://beyondgrep.com/install/). The original sources available on github are made of several packages and one main Perl file.

However, the author also offers a single Perl file that include all the packages. From the source I can tell this file was auto-generated and I would like to know how it is done.

I tried to `git clone` the sources and make the module with `perl Makefile.PL && make && make install` but I don't get any auto-generated file. I guess the answer is somewhere else.

Is there any tool for doing such things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ack` uses a home-rolled solution accessed via `make ack-standalone`.

You should have a look at [App::FatPacker](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::FatPacker) since that's what it's all about.